# Simpler Tool for Creating Core Data in Code

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on converting one of my core data models to be created in code. I found [this resource](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/creating-a-coredata-model-in-code/) and I got my coded model working, however, the whole process of doing all this seems a bit tedious to me. For a model that has a few relationships and more than two or three tables making the code for core data generator seems really tedious and repetitive. I was wondering if anybody had come up with a way to streamline the process of creating a core data model in code without having to do as much repetitive work.

Comment: Why not just use the core data modeler? Sounds more like - why use the easy way if theres a complicated one.

Comment: I am making the core data model with a static library that I would like to make available for others to use. I would, however, like to keep the core data model private when the library is distributed.